# Creating an Angular API Service to provide access to all Web APIs

Tags: angularjs

I want to create an Angular service that will allow me to access a number of `$resource`s, each that access a given API. For example, I want all of my API calls to be generated from a single service using syntax like

```
var data = API.Products.query(function() {

 $scope.products = data.Products;

});
```

**OR**

```
var data = API.Customers.get({id:123}, function() {

 $scope.customer = data;

});
```

Where Products and Customers are Angular `$resource`s that reside within my API service. Currently I am trying to do this

```
    var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute', 'ngSanitize', 'ngResource', 'API']);


    var APIService = angular.module("API", ["ngResource", function ($resource) {


                this.Products = $resource('/WebApi/Products/:type/:id', {id:'all'},
                {
                    systemUpdate: { method: 'GET' },
                });

                this.Customers = $resource('/WebApi/Customers/:type/:id', {id:'all'},
                {
                    systemUpdate: { method: 'GET' },
                });


           }]);
```

But I am getting an error during the compilation of this Service. `Uncaught Error` and when I look at the same page in Firefox, the error does not give any more detail about what is going wrong. What is the correct way to give this kind of functionality?

Here is my factory now:

```
    app.factory("API", ["ngResource", function ($resource) {


        return {
            API: {
                Alerts: $resource('/WebApi/Alert/:type/:id', { id: 'all' },
                 {
                     systemUpdate: { method: 'GET' },
                     autoArchive: { method: 'POST', url: '/WebApi/Alert/Template/:type' }
                 })
            }
        }


    }]);
```

Comment: soooooo... still no luck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just make it a factory and return the necessary resources:

```
var app = angular.module("myApp");
app.factory("API", ["$resource", function($resource) {
    return {
        API: {
            Customers: $resource('/WebApi/Customers/:type/:id', {id:'all'},
            {
                systemUpdate: { method: 'GET' },
            });
        }
    }
}]);
```

Inject when needed:

```
app.controller("myController", ["API", function(API) {
    API.Customers.Get({}, function(data) {
        //sample get call from Customers
    });
}]);
```

Comment: Have you include `ngResource` .js file as well as the app dependency in your main app file?

Comment: Yes, I have `angular-resource.js` and I inject `ngResource` into my factory.. I believe your syntax `["$resource", func...` is incorrect? I will post mine

Comment: @MattHintzke -- The syntax above is the syntax used for minifying Angular. You should only be injecting `$resource` into your factory, and `ngResource` into your module

Comment: Ok, well even if I use the exact code you gave me, I get the same error

Comment: Throw a breakpoint in the JS where the error occurs, you should be able to see the call stack to see the originating point

Comment: Ah, I figured out my problem with that Error, however now I cannot get API and $scope to exist in my Controller properly. If I inject "API" into my controller, then API has to be the first parameter in the function, `function(API, $scope) { ....` but $scope is now undefined, how can I get both?

Comment: It looks like I have to explicitly inject `$scope` into my controller... At least that works